exceeding max_connections_per_hour on bought database
Im using PHP and MySqli for my database connection on a database i bought which has max connections of 500. I dont really know or have been taught how to manage and optimise queries, but when im working on the website with my class (its a group project), it always gives this error: Uncaught msqli_sql_exception:user(my user) has exceeded the 'max_connections_per_hour' resource (value:500).Since i dont really know what connections are, i dont know what to do, becausei was already doing everything ive researched. My db.php file looks like this:
<?php
$conn= new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$password", "$database");


if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}

?>

I include this at the start of every file, and at the end of each file
i put $conn->close(). some people said it should be msqli_close($conn). Is there a difference? This is very annoying, because when we work in gorup and this happens, everyone has to download the database and use localhost to make it work, and if anyone makes changes we have to all manually edit this.
An example of a query, so you have an idea of what i might be doing wrong:
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM customer,type 
WHERE username = ? OR email = ? 
AND customer.type_id = types.id";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $usernameOrEmail, $usernameOrEmail);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

I also have no idea what is meant by "connection". Is it 500 queries? 500 page refreshes? I hope its not because that would mean that if we would get 500 customers in an hour, the website would just shut down
Ive tried to find pages where the msqli wasnt closed, but did not find any. Also, i tried to increase the max connections, but im not able to. (i would have to pay more)

PHP applications generally do not persist between web requests, so if you're being limited to a certain number of connections per hour, then the limit would be the number of hits per hour, multiplied by the number of times that your code opens a new connection, eg new mysqli(). That said, I would consider it very strange for a host to limit connections per hour rather than simultaneous connections.

Hosting is cheap these days, and you can even get free hosting with a database. Especially if you are learning something, I don't think it is worth fighting this weird restriction from a paid provider.

It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

A new connection is when you do new mysqli

You really should not put $conn->close() anywhere, especially at the end of the file.

Please stop doing this if ($conn->connect_errno) {. You should enable mysqli exceptions and you should not be checking for errors manually

"if we would get 500 customers in an hour, the website would just shut down" That's exactly what this means. Your hosting provider is ridiculous with this requirement, probably trying to force you to pay money.

@Dharman I contacted my hosting service, and they told me i probably have accumulated sessions. Could this be the issue since i use sessions to store logins? When someone is logged in, i use '$_SESSION["id"] = $id;'. Also, why should i not use $conn->close? What should i use to close my connection instead? I think the customer service person did not know anything about databases, since he told me 1 connection was one person logging into an account, which sounds stupid because how would a database know if it is a login or not.

No, you are mixing things up. The customer service person was most likely speaking from the perspective of MySQL. You think of your app. The sessions in your code have nothing to do with the sessions in MySQL. The log-ins to your app are not the log-ins they were talking about. You need to learn the difference between your PHP program and the program the service person supports (MySQL). Your app logs in to the DB every time you open a new connection. That's what the username and password you specify in new mysqli are for. It opens a session on MySQL which lasts as long as the HTTP req.

Basically, what the support person told you is nothing. They just restated the facts.

You should not close the connection because PHP does it automatically for you whenever the variable can no longer be accessed or when the PHP script ends. If your script is part of a web app and these are HTTP requests then once your PHP sends a response to the client (web browser) the MySQL session will be closed. The only time it would not happen is if you have "p:" prepended to your $host

@Dharman Yea, i already thought the customer service guy didnt really know what he was talking about. he explicitly said one login is one connection. He also said this limit is used for safety purposes, to avoid hackers, which seems stupid. I did cramp down on connections, since i was using functions, where, in each funtions, a new connection needed to be started. i fixed this by passing $conn as a parameter. i think this will definitley reduce connections since i had an admin check function on each page.

@Dharman My hosting server ALSO has a limit for simultaneous connections. which i do understand. Its just weird they have a limit for hourly connections. for one dollar a month more i can get rid of the limit, which i will probably do when this subscription runs out. Thanks for the help.
